# Action link with string id returning HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, actionlink

I would like to receive a string as the id passed from action link in a view. But for some reason I always get the error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. When I was debugging the delete code in the controller never gets executed it just throws an error. I do not understand why I cannot achieve it with the following code.

```
 //action link passing id (string) 

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete Room", "Delete", new {id=item.RoomName})|

    </td>



//controller method Delete
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
    {
        Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
        if (room == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();

        }
        return View(room);
    }



//RouteConfig.cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using link in the current controller?

Comment: Are the `Delete` action and the View that's calling `@Html.ActionLink` in the same controller?

Comment: Yes they are in the same controller .

Comment: When I change the code in action link like this :            @Html.ActionLink("Delete Room","Delete")|  the delete method in my controller  gets executed but of course it returns error as  I am not passing the id argument. But when I pass the id argument the delete method never gets executed.